# How to parse string by element tag?

Tags: c#, .net, tags, element

I have a string containing hex values, I will parse them and convert to a tagged string. Suppose here I have tags L and A, followed by the number of elements specified to determine the sequence that will need to be converted. The problem here is that I have retrieved the elements, converted them to display values, but I have the problem of not displaying the correct tags and the number of elements per tag. I think my code looks pretty ugly and unstable. Therefore, I would like to ask if you have a way to display them properly with tags according to the number elements. This is my snipped code

```
    string _str = "01 04 41 03 78 79 7A 01 04 01 00 41 07 34 35 36 20 37 38 39 01 01 41 03 31 32 33 01 00 41 03 61 62 63 01 00";
    //var _result_expect = "<L\r\n  <A \"xyz\">\r\n  <L\r\n    <L\r\n    >\r\n    <A \"456 789\">\r\n    <L\r\n      <A \"123\">\r\n    >\r\n    <L\r\n    >\r\n  >\r\n  <A \"abc\">\r\n  <L\r\n  >\r\n>.";
    bool _first_list = false, _match = false;
    string _result = "", _space = " ", _current_space = "";
    int _list_num = 0, _space_num = 0;
    while (_str.Length > 0)
    {
        if (_str.Substring(0, 2) == "41") //Is A, check if start is 41
        {
            string _ascii_str = "", _ascii_temp = "";
            int _ascii_len = 0;
            _ascii_len = Convert.ToInt32(_str.Substring(3, 2), 16); //get total element number follow this tag
            if (_ascii_len == 0)
            {
                _result = _result + _current_space + "<A>";
                _str = _str.Substring(6, _str.Length - 6).Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                _ascii_temp = _str.Substring(6, (_ascii_len * 3) - 1).Trim();
                for (int x = 0; x <= _ascii_temp.Length - 1; x = x + 3)
                {
                    string k = _ascii_temp.Substring(x, 2).Trim();
                    _ascii_str = _ascii_str + Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(k, 16)).ToString();
                }
                _str = _str.Substring(6 + (_ascii_len * 3) - 1, _str.Length - 6 - ((_ascii_len * 3) - 1)).Trim();
                _result = _result + _current_space + "<A " + "\"" + _ascii_str + "\"" + ">";
            }
            _match = true;
            _list_num = _list_num - 1;
            if (_str.Trim() == "")
                goto skipwhile;
            else
                _result = _result + "\r\n";
        }
        if (_list_num <= 0 && _result != "") //define if end of tag
        {
            _space_num = _space_num - 1;
            _current_space = _current_space.Substring(0, _current_space.Length - 2);
            _result = _result + _current_space + ">" + "\r\n";
        }
        if (_str.Substring(0, 2) == "01") //Is L, check if start is 01
        {
            _list_num = Convert.ToInt32(_str.Substring(3, 2), 16); //get total element number follow this tag
            if (_list_num == 0)
            {
                _result = _result + _current_space + "<L\r\n" + _current_space + ">";
                _list_num += 1;
                _first_list = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _result = _result + _current_space + "<L";
                _first_list = true;
            }
            _str = _str.Substring(5, _str.Length - 5).Trim();
            _match = true;                 
            if (_str.Trim() == "")
            {
                _result = _result + "\r\n" + _current_space + ">";
                goto skipwhile;
            }
            else
                _result = _result + "\r\n";
        }
        if (_match == false) //exit while if not match
        {
            goto exitwhile;
        }
        if (_list_num <= 0 || _first_list == true) //define number of space
        {
            _first_list = false;
            _space_num = _space_num + 1;
            _current_space = _current_space  + _space + _space;
        }
    }
skipwhile:
    for (int i = 1; i <= _space_num; i++)
    {
        if (i == _space_num)
        {
            _current_space = "";
        }
        if (_current_space.Length > 0)
        {
            _current_space = _current_space.Substring(0, _current_space.Length - 2);
        }
        _result = _result + "\r\n" + _current_space + ">";
    }
exitwhile:
    _result = _result + ".";
```

According to the code, the result should be like `_result_expect` value, which I have commented. As more detail in this case, look at the str with tags and the hex encode in below, they show clarify and you can look at them, which I tried to convert.

```xml
<L
  <A "xyz">
  <L
    <L
    >
    <A "456 789">
    <L
      <A "123">
    >
    <L
    >
  >
  <A "abc">
  <L
  >
>.
```

```
01 04 => L with 4 elements
41 03 78 79 7A => A with 3 character is xyz
01 04 => L with 4 elements
01 00 => L with 0 element
41 07 34 35 36 20 37 38 39 => A with 7 character is 456 789
01 01 => L with 1 elements
41 03 31 32 33 => A with 3 character is 123
01 00 => L with 0 element
41 03 61 62 63 => A with 3 character is abc
01 00 => L with 0 element
```

Comment: Throw it away and write it without goto.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a site that's geared toward, "Here's how I solved this problem. Can you find a better way?" If you wrote the code, and want a review of every aspect of it, head to the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) of [codereview.se] to see if this question could be made on topic there.

Comment: Apologized about that, but i get stuck . Can you give me some pseucode ?

Comment: You've conflated several things here: parsing, interpretation, display... You really need to take some time and rewrite it to separate those concerns. If the very first thing you did was write one method that converts the input string to a `byte[]`, you wouldn't have to do any `Substring`s or `Trim`s, and you could directly use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` to read the next N bytes following a length as a string, releasing your code of that responsibility. It would clean up this method significantly.

Comment: Ow my eyes, those `_` are doing them in.

Comment: You could use a recursive algorithm https://dotnetfiddle.net/rzEjoZ

Comment: Oh, i don't think recursive algorithm after read your comment, let me get something else from your advice.